# Exporting Nodes using drush as csv files issues

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, export-to-csv

I want to export nodes as a specific type from my drupal website as csv file using drush i have trying this command but it fails.

```
drush node-export --type=break,article --format=dsv --sql "select nid from node limit 100" --file=/root/article.csv
```

Error output:

> The directory 1 does not contain a valid Drupal installation [0.1 sec,
>   5.71 MB]

Could you please advice

Comment: Format the error message to make it more readable and remove useless tag [linux]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by the following steps :

1- I have select all the needed nids from the databases.

2- i have passed that nids to drush command as the following :

3- drush node-export --type=break,article --format=dsv nids 33 300 3012 45 --file=/root/article.csv

you have to make sure that you have node-export enabled from drupal.